# oracle sql select the table and cumulative calculate the score by the date

Tags: sql, oracle

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDMWU.jpg

```
+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID  | TERM      | SCORE    |
+-----+-----------+----------+
| 1001|   201009  |        3 | 
| 1001|   201009  |      1.5 |
| 1001|   201101  |        2 |
| 1001|   201101  |        1 | 
| 1001|   201109  |        2 | 
+-----+-----------+----------+
```

here is the table 1 that had some kind of gpa score

one person had some score in several terms

is it possible using select statement to group the term and calculate the score

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkrqu.jpg

```
+-----+-----------+--------------------+
|ID   |TERM       |      GPA           |
+-----+-----------+--------------------+
|1001 |201009     | (3+1.5)/2=2.25     |
|1001 |201101     |(3+1.5+2+1)/4=1.875 |
|1001 |201109     |(3+1.5+2+1+2)/5=1.9 |
+-----+-----------+--------------------+
```

etc....

i am using apex to make a report,it seems it create the table by select statement

is it possible select the table like that ?

Comment: how about if i want to add a column for calculate the term gpa :independent gpa of each term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to oracle server at this moment but if I remember correctly this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, term, AVG(score)
OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY term)
FROM foo;
```